# How to count the number of ocurrences of events in column and output in new colum sorted by user with pandas

Tags: python, jupyter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lj9D.png)

I'm trying to count the number of occurrences each number is found in column "event_type_id" and group by user and save it to a new column using pandas.
Ex: on Column A, User 1 completed the actions that are labeled in column C. I want to count how many times User A did event "0" and add that sum to the new column called "Post"
Can anyone help?

Comment: Hi Davi. Welcome to Stackoverflow. [Here is a guide explaining how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please provide a small sample of your data and show the code you have tried so far and any errors you get. Show what your desired output should look like. Here is a [guide showing how to format your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.